# How to import images dynamically to set as the url path for background image property in react

Tags: reactjs, url, webpack, import, background-image

I have an assets folder that store all my images.
And in the assets folder I also have a json file that has objects each has a key that holds the relative path to an image.

```
[
  {"url":"../assets/image1"},
  {"url":"../assets/image1"}
]
```

I want to be able to map through these objects in the json file and dynamically make a component that will have a div where its background-image property will be a url() and the argument of the path will be supplied through each json object.
like this:

```
function Box(props) {
  const style = {
    backgroundImage: `url(${props.imageURL})`
  }
  return(<div style={style}></div>)
}
```

It works if I specifically import the image path like this, at the top

```
import imageURL from '../assets/image1';
...
    backgroundImage: `url(${imageURL})`
...
```

But then that way it won't be dynamic.

How do I import import images dynamically to set as the url path for the background-image property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer inspired by @chonnychu

I ended up making a component that handles all the imports, and exporting all the imported stuff at the end.

While this is not the optimal solution, but it's an acceptable amount of manual work.

```
import box1image from "../assets/TimeSeriesAnalysis.png";

const boxInfo = [
  {
    id: 1,
    image: box1image,
    title: "Box 1",
    description:
      "Box 1 is the first box",
  },
];

export default boxInfo;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have a object for mapping all images url, maybe can you do this like so?

your map file

```
import bg from './bg.jpg';
import bg1 from './bg1.jpg';

export default {
  bg,
  bg1,
  ...
}
```

your component

```
import imageMap from '../assets/imageMap';

function Box() {
  const [imageUrl, setImageUrl] = React.useState(imageMap.bg);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    /* you can change image url by effects dynamically */
  }, [])

  /* you can change image url by events dynamically too */
  const handleClick = () => {
    setImageUrl(imageMap.bg1);
  }

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        backgroundImage: `url(${imageUrl})`
      }}
      onClick={handleClick}
    />
  )
}
```